# Testing of two TFS servers from the same workspace

Tags: tfs, version-control, upgrade

We have TFS 2013 SP 4 (our existing version) and TFS 2017 (which is under testing for we are upgrading the TFS version).
My question is : Is it possible to work and test on both the TFS at the same time with the same workspace?
Business users are able to configure the new TFS 2017 and work there. However, when they are switching back to TFS 2013 (since we have not gone live with TFS 2017), it throws an 'Identity does not exist error'.
Has anyone tried it? 
Is it even possible to test this way? Or shall we have one TFS version at a time for one workspace even for testing?

Thank you.

Anant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgraded TFS 2013 to TFS 2017(using TFS 2013 backup) on a new Server, the two servers have the same TFS GUID, which will confuse your Visual Studio clients.

You should avoid having two TFS up & running with the same set of GUIDs. And this is usually avoided by shutting down the old TFS server after the upgrade has finished and has been tested & verified.

Comment: Or change the Server ID (explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2019#changeserverid) and create a new workspace that points to the 2017 server (in another directory) that way you could use both.